# How can I stop emmc recovery?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, userland

I have a prebuilt Linux kernel 4.19. I can't build a fresh one. I can mount an emmc partition read-only with no issue. I have trouble mounting partitions read and write. It reports "running CQE recovery"

I am thinking of killing the recovery function when it starts after I `mount partition -o rw`. I am suspecting the function is in [core.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0a8db05b571ad5b8d5c8774a004c0424260a90bd/drivers/mmc/core/core.c#L534)
My idea would be to set the MMC_CQE_RECOVERY_TIMEOUT as a kernel command line parameter. But I don't know which parameter does that if it exists. Or I could run a function that stops the recovery. I could maybe create a binary that calls the function `mmc_cqe_request_done(mmc, mrq)` from [cqhci-core.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0a8db05b571ad5b8d5c8774a004c0424260a90bd/drivers/mmc/host/cqhci-core.c#L809) but I don't have access to `mmc, mrq` parameters since im not making a kernel driver or maybe I can create the parameters somehow from a block device itself after booting the kernel and running `mknod()`. Which of these is possible?

I am not trying to patch any kernel source I want to know if it's possible to stop running QCE recovery by creating a binary I can run or use a kernel parameter that can stop qce recovery.

Comment: Which bit are you having problems with?  When you say you "don't have access", are you saying you don't know how to read a module parameter?  What you're proposing (replacing the fixed timeout with a parameter) seems like a reasonable choice, and might be valuable to others.  Show us what you have implemented so far, and what's missing - at the moment, we have very little idea of which part you're struggling with.

Comment: Seems like a bunch of XY questions. Regardless, this seems all off-topic for this site.

Comment: There were kernel patches for related issues: https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-mmc/patch/1588868135-31783-1-git-send-email-vbadigan@codeaurora.org/ and https://www.spinics.net/lists/stable/msg567716.html

Comment: @TobySpeight I am not making a driver. I was trying to check if I could make it timeout from a binary or a kernel parameter. I have not implemented anything yet.

Comment: @sawdust patches wont work since I can't build a fresh kernel

Comment: It seems that you're just _operating_ or _configuring_ your system, rather than  __programming__, so Stack Overflow isn't an appropriate place to ask.  This question _might_ be suitable for [unix.se]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I asked the question I had no idea device tree blobs could be modified. My goto solution was the impression I could run code in userspace to stop the recovery. I found a simpler solution. Which has nothing to do with writing code.

The problem was I needed to stop the command queue and I had no idea how to do it and didn't know where it was being enabled in the first place.

It turns out the device tree has `mediatek,cqhci` property which isn't supported well by the kernel. It seems my kernel sources probably had it enabled by patching their kernel sources since it wasn't available for mainline MEDIATEK mmc

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    mmc@11230000 {
        compatible = "mediatek,mt6768-mmc";
        mediatek,cqhci;
    };
};
```

So I had to modify the device tree file with fdtput.

```
fdtput -d /path/to/fdt /mmc@11230000 "mediatek,cqhci"
```

Steps

1. I dumped the device tree blob from the boot.img
2. I [Binwalked](https://manpages.org/binwalk) through the blob to get the pure flattened device tree
3. Deleted the command queue enabler property from the blob with [fdtput](https://manpages.org/fdtput)